# Implement natural order comparator for non-comparable list

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I'm implementing the `List` interface for a clone of `ArrayList`. I'm trying to implement `sort` ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-)):
[image: java.util.List sort method]
I'm not sure how to implement the case where the comparator is null. My `ArrayList` does not extend `Comparable` because I want to be able to store non-comparable objects in the list. I've tried using the following for the `sort` method:

```
public void sort(Comparator<? super E> c){
    if(c == null){
        // Use ascending order
        class ascComparator<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Comparator<T> {
            public int compare(T a, T b) {
                return a.compareTo(b);
            }
        }
        c = new ascComparator<E>();
    }
    // Implementation of merge sort goes here
}
```

This expectedly gives an error as `E` does not extend `Comparable`. In the above documentation it is stated "if ... is null then all elements in this list must implement the Comparable interface". How do I check that the objects in the list implement `Comparable` and how do I then use `compareTo` without getting an error? Is there just a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what `ArrayList` does, try:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        objects.add(new Object());
        objects.add(new Object());

        objects.sort(null);
    }
}
```

Your comparator must just assume that the objects in the list are Comparable, that's the best it can do:

```
 class ascComparator implements Comparator<Object> {
            public int compare(Object a, Object b) {
                return ((Comparable)a).compareTo(b);
            }
        }
```

Which will throw a `ClasscastException` if the items in your list are not `Comparable`.

Comment: This is the behaviour I'd like to implement but my code as it is will not compile. How do I achieve something like this?

Comment: Thank you, I just had to add `@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})` to the `sort` method as well and then it was fine. I am writing the sort myself, but surely I still use the comparator?

Comment: True, you do use your comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do the unsafe cast.  There's really no way around it.

Comment: How do I do this, my current code will not compile (becuase `E` does not extend `Comparable`)?

Comment: You have to suppress the warning.

Comment: It wasn't a warning, it was a compiler error but it's fixed now.